# How to center text in raw react-shadow-text without losing binding to text shadow

Tags: reactjs, styling, shadow, react-component

I'm learning how to style React components and use npm to import libraries that i can use to do different things. I have imported react-shadow-text and tried to implement a simple h1 with text shadow. When attempting to style it, all of my styles work but when I center the text within the component, the shadow does not center along with the text. If i do not center the text and i resize the browser. the shadow stays with the text as you would expect but as soon as you apply justify-content, text-align, or any centering property to the component, the text will center itself but the shadow remains to the left and the shadow does not stay in the center with the text and instead remains to the left during resizing, making itself further away from the text.

I have tried using flexbox centering and i've also tried without flex. I've also tried to style the component with different styling techniques such as css modules and inline styles. I'm sure it's something simple, but i can't really find anything on the issues specifically regarding this particular library without using native.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShadowText from 'react-shadow-text';
import styles from '../Name.css'; //imported stylesheet working
import styled from 'styled-components';
//import styles from '../Name.css';

class Name extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <ShadowText className="name" theme={{
          shadowTextColor: 'Black',
          shadowTextShadowColor: 'Black',
          shadowTextShadowBlur: '6px',
          shadowTextXTranslate: '0px',
          shadowTextYTranslate: '15px',
          textShadowOffset: '0px', //tried messing with this
          shadowTextTransitionDuration: '0.4s',
          shadowTextTransitionTiming: 'ease-in-out',
        }}>
          Larry Young
        </ShadowText>
    );
  }
}

export default Name;
```

And CSS

```
.name {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: 'Cinzel';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  text-align: center; //problem child. without this, text stays to the left 
                      //but shadow attaches itself to text. When this is 
                      //added, or justify content is added, text detaches 
                      //from shadow effect. Positioning issue maybe?
}
```

I've tried using anchorShadow prop built in to the npm library and setting it to true and it just flips the text and the shadow and does the same thing, but the shadow stays in place and the text moves...I've also tried CSS Modules css.js as well and inline styles. I guess I could try using raw text-shadow css but it kind of defeats the purpose in learning this particular library. I assume lack of experience with React is what's biting me. Thanks everyone.

Comment: After looking through react dev tools i noticed that this package makes a seperate div containing the shadow. Would it possibly be because this created shadow div is positioned relative?

Comment: I've also tried to wrap the Shadowtext component in it's own div and centering the div. I can get close this way but it's just not close enough

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when the react-text-shadow library adds the shadow, it does so in a seperate div that is absolute positioned. If I take away the positioning in dev tools, the shadow leaps to the center. So i tried isolating that class in index.css in the create-react app environment and changed the position value. When doing so, it worked, until I tried to edit the shadow offset to line it up more precisely. As soon as I changed the properties to control shadowTranslateXorY and reload, it generates a new class for the shadow, which negates the positioning change I made in the master index.css file. For now, I will just use CSS text-shadow. Putting text-shadow into the css file for the component, importing it into the component, and referencing to it with className is working fine. Hopefully someone else knows a little bit more about this particular library. I can't seem to find much documentation about it, aside from what is on the NPM page when you install.